# Is accesskey attribute really case sensitive?

Tags: html, semantics, access-keys

The [specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#the-accesskey-attribute) says:

> If specified, the value must be an ordered set of unique space-separated tokens that are **case-sensitive**, each of which must be exactly one Unicode code point in length.

However, as far as I have tested, it doesn't seems to be the case. Firefox uses `Alt + Shift + key` (in which case, case-sensitivity would be a problem because `shift` is commonly used for caps). There is no difference at all if I enable or disable caps lock.

Do you know any browser/device/OS which is case sensitive with this attribute ? Can I use safely `accesskey="A"` and `accesskey="a"` without expecting a difference ?

Answer (score 0):

This when specification begins to differsr with actual browsers configurations. In fact, the specification is a guide to create a standard. Those who contribute in browsers projects are free to do something else.